# I have been trying this code but Exit for not working. Can someone suggest the correction?

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following code and Exit for is not working in this

```
p = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 372 - j).Value, (Capacities_sheet.Range(Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 76), Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 147))), False)

For m = 1 To p
    If TempBestload >= (SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 78).Value * 0.9) Then
        Exit For
        Bestslot.Cells(1 + i, 6).Value = SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 372 - j).Value
    Else:
        TempBestslot2 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value, Capacities_sheet.Range("A:EQ"), (Application.Match(SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 372 - j).Value, (Capacities_sheet.Range(Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 1), Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 147))), False) - m), False)

        'If capacity is not zero for previous slot
        If TempBestslot2 <> 0 Then
            TempBestload = TempBestload + TempBestslot2
            Bestslot.Cells(4, 8 + a).Value = TempBestload
            Bestslot.Cells(5, 8 + a).Value = SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 372 - j).Value
            k = k + 1
            Bestslot.Cells(2, 8 + a).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 2).Value, (Capacities_sheet.Range(Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 1), Capacities_sheet.Cells(37, 1))), False)
            Bestslot.Cells(3, 8 + a).Value = 75 + Application.WorksheetFunction.Match((SLA_scenarios.Cells(1 + i, 372 - j).Value), (Capacities_sheet.Range(Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 76), Capacities_sheet.Cells(1, 147))), False) - m + 1

        'If capacity is zero then check the next best slot
        Else:
            GoTo NextIteration2
            k = 0
        End If
    End If
Next m
```

Comment: Which line does not work?

Comment: _not working_ is not really a helpful description. Additionally the line `Bestslot.Cells(1 + i, 6).Value = SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 372 - j).Value` after `Exit For` can never be reached. If that's your problem then you need to put `Exit For` after that line.

Answer (score 1):

You have two lines of code that are never run.

```
...
If TempBestload >= (SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 78).Value * 0.9) Then
    'This next line exits the For m = 1 To p loop entirely. The next code
    'that runs is under the Next m code line
    Exit For
    'This next line will never be run.
    Bestslot.Cells(1 + i, 6).Value = SLA_scenarios.Cells(i + 1, 372 - j).Value
Else:
...

...
    Else:
        'This next line moves execution to the NextIteration2 label. The next line
        'of code that executes is under the NextIteration2: label.
        GoTo NextIteration2
        'This next line will never be run.
        k = 0
    End If
...
```

If you want those code lines to execute, move them above the redirection code lines. e.g. move `k = 0` above `GoTo NextIteration2`.

Additionally, I don't see the point of the `:` in `Else:`. The `:` is for putting two lines of code onto the same line. It's typically used by coders that don't like using vertical space so they group mundane (but related) code lines onto a single line. e.g.

```
dim i as long: i = 10
```

Just delete the `:` and use `Else`.